# Does latest version of thingsboard gateway support MultiTenant?

Tags: thingsboard-gateway

I was trying to add **multi tenant in latest Thingsboard gateway**, but all i could see is single tenant.
It seems latest vesrion of Gateway does not support it.

Can anyone help me in setting up multi-tenant on GW.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they've removed this configuration because the previous version of the gateway supported multi-tenancy, I'm facing the same issue too.
http://v14.thingsboard.io/docs/iot-gateway/multi-tenant-configuration/